# Wait 5 seconds before download button appear

Tags: javascript, python, django, timer

I know how to do that with javascript but I need a secure way to do it.
Anybody can view page source, get the link and do not wait 5 seconds.

Is there any solution? I'm working with javascript and django.
Thanks!

Comment: There is no SECURE way with just clientside code. You can make an Ajax call to the server to get the link and have validation the serve that checks for time....

Comment: Load a link after 5  secs using AJAX?

Comment: use serverside timeout.. whenever there is (AJAX) request from client for download link halt the request at server side for ~5 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only secure way would be to put the logic on the server that checks the time. Make an Ajax call to the server. If the time is under 5 seconds, do not return the HTML, if it is greater than , than return the html to show.

Other option is to have the link point to your server and if the time is less than five seconds it redirects them to a different page. If it is greater than 5, it will redirect them to the correct content.

Either way, it requires you to keep track of session time on the server and remove it from the client.

Comment: Did you check the `Demo`, if yes, why this is not secure?

Comment: Obfuscation does not equal secure.

Comment: At least cannot be changed in browser

Comment: It can be reversed...it is not secure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax, retrieve the button source code from your back end and intert it on your page.

Something like

```
$.get('url', function(sourceCode) {
    $('#midiv').html(sourceCode);
});
```

Comment: This will take additional time to load content.

Comment: You also missed `)` of the `get()`

Answer (score 0):

Use server side timeout.. whenever there is (AJAX) request from client for download link with timestamp, compare the client sent timestamp with currenttime and derive how much time is required to halt the request at server side to make up ~5 seconds. So by comparing timestamp you can almost achieve accuracy of waiting time as the network delays would be taken into account automatically.